# Authenticate Users However I want

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm look at Web API 2 with a project that I created as a "proof of concept". I'm trying to see where I inject my own code for customer authentication. I have an internal auth/login service that I would like to call to determine if login credentials are valid and then get user values (id, roles, etc) if it was valid.

I created the project with "Individual Accounts" as the authentication type but I'm having a hard time figuring out where I'm going to call my service and then map the result to an IdentityUser (or some IUser) object.

In the generated `ApplicationOAuthProvider` class there is code that passes username and password from a context object like so:

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    using (UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager = _userManagerFactory())
    {
        IdentityUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);
    // ...
```

How do I hook into that call?

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

- Create your own `HTTP Message Handler` to authenticate the user. You can put your custom code there. This will execute every request, then you can set the credential in the pipeline of the execution.

  [HTTP Message Handlers](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/http-message-handlers)
- Create or use the default filters to handle the Authorization

  [Authentication and Authorization in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: How would that work with the boiler plate code that I get with the authentication type I selected? I'm wanting to keep bearer tokens because the service that I'm prototyping will be for mobile app and mobile web clients. I think it would be beneficial to have the code generated work for my situation if possible rather than writing all of the functionality from the ground up.

Comment: You will consume the credentials from the request, using the Message Handler, then access the auth/login service to get user values (id, roles, etc) if it was valid. You can keep the default Authorization filters on the role.

Comment: Gotcha, maybe I need to rethink my implementation because I want to prevent sending username/password credentials each client request.

Comment: You can create a custom token and send it back to say It's authenticated, but you will need to create your own AuthorizationFilter to check out this token.